# PostgreSQL CREATE TYPE using multiple relations?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, database-theory, composite-types

I'm becoming familiar with PostgreSQL's ability to define a data type https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html using `CREATE TYPE` syntax.

It appears to me that this type does not allow to compose a type out of relations/tables. In other words, I can do this:

`CREATE TYPE compfoo AS (f1 int, f2 text);`

but I can't do

`CREATE TYPE compfoo AS (f1 relation, f2 relation);`

I was wondering if my understanding is correct, and if not, how one could achieve the latter?

I want to indicate that I don't have any particular application for it. I would actually be interested in starting a discussion on an application! I am just trying to expand my understanding of this feature which is often touted as a very powerful feature in the extensible DBMS world.

Comment: what do you mean? can you give an example?

Comment: *"CREATE TYPE compfoo AS (f1 relation, f2 relation);"* For some reason it feels like you are looking for [Inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html) instead

Comment: .. also it feels like you are looking for `MULTISET` (ANSI/ISO SQL 2003)

Answer (score 0):

The old version with support is 9.4 today and i can achieve your case, and then in the recent version too.

for example:

```
create table a ( i int, j int);
create table b ( k text, l text);
CREATE TYPE compfoo AS (f1 a, f2 b);
create table c (m compfoo );
insert into c values ( row(row(1,2),row('hello','world'))   );
select * from c;

result:
("(1,2)","(hello,world)")
```

you can check this test in 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=4499c5d52e876979d81fb3f2537c2439

check your version

Comment: I'm talking about passing a table or relation `type` instead of a table. Sorry if unclear.

Comment: In PostgreSQL a  table automatically becomes a data type